# Populate UITableView with array

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

The UITableView just show the second value of array... Where's my error?

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) {
```

UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellID);

```
        if (cell == null) {
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, cellID);
        }

string firstValue = "Hello"
string secondValue = "Bye"

string[] concat = {firstValue, secondValue};

        foreach(string op in concat){
                cell.TextView.Text = op;
        }

return cell;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are making multiple assignments to the same variable, so the last assignment will overwrite any previous assignments.  To **append** text you can use the `+=` operator

```
foreach(string op in concat){
        cell.TextView.Text += op;
}
```

Comment: This totally answers the question; however, depending on how many items are actually in concat, it may have better performance to StringBuilder.Append()

Answer (score 0):

The foreach statement will loop through each string in your array and set the cell's textView's text property to the currently looped string.

Try:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) {
UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellID);

if (cell == null) {
    cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, cellID);
}

string firstValue = "Hello"
string secondValue = "Bye"

string[] concat = {firstValue, secondValue};

foreach(string op in concat){
    cell.TextView.Text += op;
}

return cell;

}
```

This will concatenate each string in the array to your cell's textView's text. So it will result in "Hello Bye".

---

**EDIT:** If you want use each of your array value on a new row:

```
 public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) {
    UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellID);



if (cell == null) {
    cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, cellID);
}

string firstValue = "Hello"
string secondValue = "Bye"

string[] concat = {firstValue, secondValue};

cell.TextView.Text = concat[indexPath!.row];

return cell;

}
```

Comment: You're right, it help a little, but I don't want to concat in the same row... This way the two strings are write together. I want to complete the table with firstValue in a row and secondValue another row

Comment: I don't have how to use indexPath!.row.

Comment: I don't have ".row" and "!"

Comment: Try just "indexPath.row"

Comment: Return "Array index is out of range"

Comment: That's because you have more rows than strings in your array. Add as many strings in your array as your rows count or set the rows count to 2.

Comment: I try to use "int x = uuids.Length;
       tableView.NumberOfRowsInSection (x);"

Didn't work ;s...